# How can I copy an asset to a virtual folder

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-media-services

Since Media Services does not let us upload from stream and does not let us create virtual folder, I decided to upload my images and videos to blob containers structured with virtual folders.

Next we need to process images and videos with azure media services face redactor.

Therefore, we need to copy our blobs to azure media services as assets and then use face redactor and then we need to upload the result that are in the form of asset back to it's respective virtual folder.

The problem is that Azure media services do not let us upload asset directly to another container with a specific virtual path, or so I think that's the case.

How would one approach this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our .Net SDK does provide a few methods to upload from Stream (see the last UploadAsync overload near the bottom of [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-media-services/blob/dev/src/net/Client/Entities/IAssetFile.cs) page).

We don’t support a virtual directory structure in our Assets, though. As Bruce Chen has responded, you could use Azure Storage APIs to go back and forth between your blob container with virtual folders, and the blob container that holds the Azure Media Services Asset.

Comment: I am using asp .net core.
I just came across an issue where the sdk is not compatible with asp .net core.

I tried to use media services rest api for face redactor, however I could not find. Is it because it does not exist? Or have I just not found it?

Comment: We do not have a .NET Core API yet. You would have to use the REST APIs.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the asset files under a specific asset could only under the root folder. If you want to copy the asset files to another virtual folder under another blob container, I assumed that you could first retrieve the Asset by using the MediaServices SDK, then you could use the storage client SDK to retrieve the asset files and copy to your desired destination under another blob container. Here is the code snippet, you could refer to it:

```
//retrieve the asset with the specific Id
var asset = _context.Assets.Where(s => s.Id == "nb:cid:UUID:39a13eaf-48cf-4c3c-80d6-bcd6b3b7c8b4").FirstOrDefault();

//retrieve the container name for the current asset
string assetContainerName = asset.Uri.Segments[1];

//construct the CloudBlobClient instance
StorageCredentials mediaServicesStorageCredentials = new StorageCredentials("{storage-name}", "storage-key");
var storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(mediaServicesStorageCredentials, true);
var mediaServiceBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

//construct the CloudBlobContainer instance for the current asset container
var assetContainer = mediaServiceBlobClient.GetContainerReference(assetContainerName);

//define the destination directory under another container
var destDirectory = mediaServiceBlobClient.GetContainerReference("images").GetDirectoryReference("2017/11/7");

//copy the asset files under the current asset container to the specific virtual folder under another blob container
foreach (CloudBlockBlob assetBlob in assetContainer.ListBlobs())
{
    var targetBlob = destDirectory.GetBlockBlobReference(assetBlob.Name);
    targetBlob.StartCopy(assetBlob);
}
```

Comment: I am using asp .net core. I just came across an issue where the media services sdk is not compatible with asp .net core. I tried to use media services rest api for face redactor, however I could not find the apis for face redactor. Is it because it does not exist? Or have I just not found it?

Comment: For using Face Redactor from .NET Core, you would have to wrap the REST API as you noted. I'll paste the code below outside of this comment

Answer (score 0):

To use FaceRedactor in .NET Core, use the REST API directly to Create a Job with the right Media Processor ID and configuration settings.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-face-redaction

curl -X POST \
  https://tvmewest.restv2.westcentralus-2.media.azure.net/api/Jobs \
  -H 'accept: application/json;odata=verbose' \
  -H 'authorization: Bearer **YOUR AAD JWT BEARER TOKEN HERE**
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json;odata=verbose' \
  -H 'dataserviceversion: 3.0' \
  -H 'maxdataserviceversion: 3.0' \
  -H 'postman-token: 6662e359-cb76-d849-11c5-99da0514cdc1' \
  -H 'user-agent: azure media services postman collection' \
  -H 'x-ms-version: 2.15' \
  -d '{
  "Name": "Redaction Test Job",
  "InputMediaAssets": [{
    "__metadata": {
      "uri": "https://tvmewest.restv2.westcentralus-2.media.azure.net/api//Assets('\''nb:cid:UUID:733f8d88-f96b-496c-a46e-38c037b89d48'\'')"
    }
  }],
  "Tasks": [{
    "Configuration": "{'\''version'\'':'\''1.0'\'', '\''options'\'': {'\''Mode'\'': '\''Combined'\'', '\''BlurType'\'': '\''High'\''}}",
    "MediaProcessorId": "nb:mpid:UUID:3806d7a6-4985-4437-b098-50e3733310e8",
    "TaskBody": "
                
                    JobInputAsset(0)
                    JobOutputAsset(0)
                "
  }]
}'

Comment: Send me email at amshelp@microsoft.com if you want a Postman collection to play with. It makes it easier to generate code samples.